# Hello World “Conversion to Dalvik format failed”

Tags: android, format, dalvik

I've installed the following development environment on my 10.6.5:

- Eclipse SDK 3.6.1
- Android SDK Tools r8
- Android SDK Platform-tools r1
- Android SDK 2.2
- Android SDT 8.0.1

Then when I create the [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) I get the error:

**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**

I have tried everything, since this error has appeared in the past for many reasons, but I still have the same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate, search stackoverflow before posting

Comment: duplicates here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed%22.

Comment: It's not duplicated because as I said this error has appeared in the past for many different reasons. So I think this is a new reason who nobody has an answer: Hellow World fails after installing everything following the instructions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this issue because I found a solution: Netbeans!!

I lost many hours trying to compile the Android Hello World example with Eclipse. I decided to try Netbeans and it just worked.

I'm close to finish my project now and I can assure you that Netbeans is perfect to develop for Android platform. Hope it helps to anyone who is unhappy with Eclipse and Android. I have used Eclipse to develop with C++/Linux, PHP....no hard issues like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try what is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835044/error-launching-first-test-application-android-packaging-problem/5088232#5088232).

This is a very grey area as far as whether or not it is a duplicate question. If you follow the link provided by @unhillbilly you will see that there are many questions covering the same topic, with varying subtleties and variances. Currently there are 40 other questions covering the same subject, the point that unhillbilly is making is that this community works best when duplicate and similar questions are reduced or eleminated, makes it easier for us newbies to find the answers we need to keep from pulling our hair out in frustration. Likely as not, you will not find *exactly* what you are looking for, but you will find *plenty* to get you going in the right direction with out having to ask.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your response kingsolmn. See my answer to my question. I finally found a solution. I hope it helps to any who is having the same problem. Happy coding! :)