# Error launching first test application: Android Packaging Problem?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: 
wrapper was not properly loaded first   
[project]       
Android Packaging Problem
```

I've never worked with Java or eclipse before, I'm following [this introductory guide](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html) and all searches via google return no helpful results. I'm guessing the problem is I have built Android stuff with eclipse properly but I have no idea, I followed this guide to the letter and everything went as it explains it should.

[image: Here is what I have compiled]
Any ideas what caused this problem, or is it specific to the guide? If so I'll post on their help page.

I have tried doing project -> source -> clean up, but that didn't fix anything.

Edit:

I went to Project -> Android tools -> Dex bytecode and it reported:

```
DexDump: missing classex.dex for project. Please compile first.
```

So I guess that's my problem! Not sure how to solve though.

Comment: Actually I get the same result
[2011-01-29 23:08:25 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-01-29 23:08:25 - old] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

I installed everything the way it was supposed to according to the guidlines on the eclips developer homepage. I just created a project and it was an error from the beginning.

Has anyody solved this

Comment: I had the same problem.  When i checked the Manifest file.  It showed me a warning stating that "Attribute minSdkVersion (11) is higher than the project target API level (8)".  I updated my SDK to newer version.  And the problem was solved.

Comment: In my specific case i had this problem while downloading a new SDK from "Android SDK and AVD Manager", once the download was completed the issue disappeared

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said, I had the same problem so I tried all the different versions and
then I stopped filling in the SDK-version number
and finally it did not complain anymore about the wrapper.
After that it was totally fine to write the SDK-version when I created new projects.

Hope it works out for you too.

Comment: I re-installed Eclipse, went through the configuration process for Android SDK again and then deployed a new application *with* the mini-SDK Version set to null, it now runs fine! Either I messed up the original process some how, or your solution was the correct one, I suspect the latter so I've marked your answer the correct one. Thank you, greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: This "answer" could benefit from more clear instructions. Firstly close eclipse. Then open AndroidManifest.xml in a text editor. Delete the uses-sdk element then save and exit the editor. Fire up eclipse. It should build ok now. Now go to the manifest editor and enter the details you wish to have in the uses-sdk element.

Comment: @Declan. Your advice is awesome. You should make this as answer. I thinks this error is hard to explain well.

Answer (score 9):

Go to **Project** -> **Clean**

It will rebuilt workspace and fix the errors if any.

Comment: it didn't work under Windows, but what worked was restarting Eclipse

Comment: This doesn't work, @noloman restarting works for me too (Mac)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem (running on Windows 7). I resolved it by running Eclipse with Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 4):

try to run eclipse under administrator permission. Problem may be resolve.

I think you installed the SDK in "Program Files" folder . So for do something inside, must have administrator permission.

Comment: Nice answer. I too had followed all the steps in the intro. Didn't think I would need to take a step like not specifying the Min SDK, and this answer makes sense in that I did use "Program Files". If you're new to Android and accept Windows defaults during setup, you will most likely do this.  +1 from me!

Answer (score 3):

One thing that may help is to create a new test Android project.

1. In Eclipse, select File → New → Android Project.
2. Set the project name to "Test3", check Android 2.3 for the build target, type "com.example.android.apps.test3" for the package name, and type "Test3Activity" in the "Create Activity:" text box. The form should look like:

   [image: Screenshot of the resulting New Android Project form]
3. Click Finish.
4. Expand the entry for "Test3" in the Package Explorer. Navigate to `res/values/strings.xml`. Double click on the entry for `strings.xml`:

   [image: Screenshot of "Test3" in the Package Explorer]
5. Set the text content of the `string` element having name "app_name" to "Test3":

   [image: Screenshot of XML editor with the described changes to strings.xml]
6. Right click on "Test3" in the Package Explorer and select Run As → Android Application. The emulator should open and after a long while, you should see:

   [image: Screenshot of the Test3 app running within the emulator]

If these steps do not work, then you probably have an error in your installation.

Try it out and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier today. Google was largely unhelpful.

I fixed it by removing the project from eclipse, then re-importing it.

[According to this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14449) the problem is caused by upgrading to version 9 of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same HelloWorld problem with Ubuntu 64 Lucid / Eclipse 3.5.2 from Ubuntu repository. Restarting Eclipse did the trick, though I notice it still fusses about API level requirement when HelloWorld is run.

Answer (score 1):

Running it as Administrator has solved this issue for me..

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem - occurred after I tried downloading Android platform v2.3.3 (was using 3.1 and 3.2 earlier) and it interrupted in the middle - restarted eclipse and cleaned all projects and rebuilt and the problem went away

Answer (score 0):

At what point in this tutorial/guide are you running into this problem and did you make sure to include your package information in each file or ie com.something.somethingelse at the top of your class or classes?

Perhaps a registry error or maybe even a problem with activity implementation.

Please post your code if this did not start you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check:

Make sure you have the latest version oF Eclipse (Helios)
Make sure that you have the Android SDK plug-in for Eclipse.

Now if you have done that... Make sure that any classes you add (Each screen you view on Android is a class and is called an Activity) are in your androidmanifext.xml file See http://wrenbjor.com/2011/01/12/the-androidmanifest-xml-file/ for help on understanding this process.

otherwise make sure there are no red x's in your code or it wont work.

If you still have problems post some code and we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem the other night. Upgraded to Helios (3.6) and it went away, quite possibly as a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

Under windows 7, rather than run eclipse as an admin, change the permissions on the eclipse folder so the creator/owner has full control, and do the same with the folder the android SDK is installed into.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Eclipse using the files provided by Windows' native ZIP extractor. I deleted the files and took them from 7-Zip instead. Now the error is gone. So maybe using another ZIP extraction tool will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I resolved it using following steps(using eclipse helios  and windows XP ) :-

- Right click on eclipse.exe.
- click on Run As...
- Uncheck the checkbox  before **"protect my computer from unauthorized activity"**.
  And it is running for me as expected !
  hope it will also run for you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently got this when failing upgrade using adb-manager with eclipse open (win32). As eclipse was open, upgrade failed. Then returning to my project this problem occured.

Was solved by closing eclipse, restart as administrator and cleaned project.