# Automatically getting error in project when I open it in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting an error everytime i try to open a project that doesn't have any.

I get these error messages in the console section of eclipse:

```
[2011-07-21 19:17:54 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
[2011-07-21 19:17:54 - Sound Board Template] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've tried to clean, restart Eclipse and build?

Comment: This looks to be related to a previously asked question on here. [Error Launching First Test Application, Android Packaging Problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835044/error-launching-first-test-application-android-packaging-problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installing the android SDK?