# "Conversion to Dalvik format failed" error not going away

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, dx

`"Conversion to Dalvik format failed: unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first"`

I am getting this error with my project in eclipse, and I searched for it and all answers say it's a problem with .jar file conflicts, and to clean the project and it should work. There is only one .jar file in the library, and cleaning it didn't make it go away. In fact, I cleaned all projects, and it made the same error occur on my other projects!! I haven't done anything with Eclipse since the last time I successfully ran my project. I went to the store, came back and tried to run it again, and got this error. I downloaded OEM drivers for a new Asus tablet, but I don't think that did it... They're still in my downloads folder! What happened??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have no clue what was going on.... I tried a whole bunch of stuff, and made the "Conversion to dalvik format failed" error go away randomly, but java.lang.Object still could not be resolved because the AndroidManifest.XML was not synced. So I just made a new project in the workspace and copied all the text for each file, and it worked. But wait.... The original project works now, too!! What in the world!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use directly [DX utility](http://wing-linux.sourceforge.net/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#dx) (converter from JVM bytecode to Dalvik VM bytecode) instead of relying upon Eclipse.

As a result you will see what DX reports - which class from your .JAR can't be converted to .dex file

Answer (score 0):

Try this, an answer posted by User Declan Shanaghy:

`Firstly close eclipse. Then open AndroidManifest.xml in a text editor. Delete the uses-sdk element then save and exit the editor. Fire up eclipse. It should build ok now. Now go to the manifest editor and enter the details you wish to have in the uses-sdk element.`

Read more here in this link(Where I got the answer):
[Error launching first test application: Android Packaging Problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835044/error-launching-first-test-application-android-packaging-problem)

Hope I could be of help :D

Comment: `The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`
Error appears next to package name in activity.java.
And when I try to open AndroidManifest.xml, it says the resource is out of sync with the file system. I think I may just build the project from scratch!

Comment: Although it is a pain, it often helps to reinstall Eclipse. Try saving the existing project and importing it after the fresh install.