# how to make application with android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a new android apps but it says me like this

> [2011-08-18 15:27:39 - jeetu] Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
>   Unable to execute dex: wrapper was not properly loaded first

What does it mean?

Comment: Make sure you installed the SDK correctly: [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html). I suggest you using Eclipse and ADT plugin for comfortability.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4835044/469210

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir hello can you please add me as your face book friend, right now i send a freind request to you.

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

Thats pretty good place to start

Answer (score 1):

You can read developers guide. It is really good. - http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

I love reading ***Pragmatic Hello Android*** also..
  link - http://pragprog.com/book/eband3/hello-android

Answer (score 0):

I'd say leave NotePad example aside and start with Eclipse and ADT. Its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A good tutorial to start : 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

For your error, Go to Project -> Clean, it will rebuilt workspace and fix the error